# Using separate buffers in OpenGL ES 2.0 and Indices information

Tags: android, opengl-es

Currently I am writing a small Open GL ES 2.0 application to get an understanding of how it works. I made a simple .obj loader to pull in a model and render it to my phones screen. So far I've achieved some relative success in rendering the object to screen purely based on the vertices.

What I'm confused on is how to take additional information like the normal into consideration.

```
//Get handle to vertex shader's vPosition member.
        int mPositionHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(_sProgram, "vPosition");

        //Get handle to vertex shader's vNormal member.
        int mNormalHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(_sProgram, "vNormal");

        // Enable generic vertex attribute array
        GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);

        // Pass in the position information
        GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mNormalHandle);

        GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(mPositionHandle, 3, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, modelLoader.getVertBuffer());

        GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(mNormalHandle, 3, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, modelLoader.getNormalBuffer());

        // Get handle to shape's transformation matrix
        int mtrxhandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(_sProgram, "uMVPMatrix");

        // Apply the projection and view transformation
        GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(mtrxhandle, 1, false, projViewMat, 0);

        GLES20.glDrawElements(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, modelLoader.getIndices().length, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, modelLoader.getIndBuffer());
```

I have the vertices here and in the indices buffer I am basically saving locations to the vertices for each face so:

```
v[0] = x y z
v[1] = x y z
v[2] = x y z

Indices for face 1 = 0 1 2
```

What I'm unsure is how I'm supposed to define what normal is tied to what vertices. Am I supposed to include this information in with the indices and have something like?

```
Indices for face 1 = 0 1 2 n1 n1 n1
```

Can anyone explain to me how this is set up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do it like that, at least not in OpenGL ES.

In Desktop GL, AMD has an extension [`GL_AMD_interleaved_elements`](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/AMD/interleaved_elements.txt) that lets you cram multiple discrete attribute indices into a single array of indices. However, normally each index is taken to mean: ***Pull position and all other vertex attributes from index <XYZ>***. You will have to have as many normal vertex attributes as you have position vertex attributes.

There is an alternative that involves vertex texture fetches, but it is slow and not well supported (vertex texture fetches are optional in ES 2.0). Your best bet is going to be to duplicate the normal attributes so that you have a 1:1 relationship between position and normal. It will require more memory, but it is the best performing and most compatible solution.

Comment: So what I'll have to do is build the buffer as a compact buffer and have it so that the buffer reads x, y, z, nx, ny, nz? I am still confused because if it is done this way won't I be making multiples of the same normal which would be inefficient?

Comment: Yes, this is what you have to do. And yes, it is inefficient from a storage perspective. However, hardware works best when it can fetch all of the vertex data it needs for a triangle without jumping all around your vertex array. A lot of cache in the vertex stage is dedicated to post-T&L (that is, storing the values computed after the vertex shader runs) so that triangles with shared vertices do not transform the same vertex over and over, because that is ultimately a far more inefficient thing to have happen than storing duplicate vertex attributes.

Comment: GDDR is pretty high latency, so you want to fetch as much ***useful*** information as possible in a single operation. It is also high bandwidth, so the two things tend to cancel themselves out if the data is structured properly. Interleaving vertex data is one way of properly structuring data for that purpose. You don't have to do it that way, you could have separate buffers, but you would still need to have 1 normal for every position. The wide variety of memory architectures on embedded devices makes this complicated, but generally interleaved arrays are good even if they duplicate data.

Comment: Thanks, it is a pretty sloppy way to do it but it's something I can't help I guess.